# Не могу остановить цикл в Питоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot, while, telebot

```
def random_rus_30m():
text = ['Держите руки в чистоте, '
        '\nЧасто мойте их с мылом или используйте дезинфицирующее средство, '
        '\nперед едой обязательно мойте руки.', 'Старайтесь не касаться рта, носа или глаз немытыми руками;',
        '\nНа работе регулярно очищайте поверхности и устройства, '
        '\nк которым вы прикасаетесь (клавиатура компьютера, панели оргтехники общего использования, '
        '\nэкран смартфона, пульты, дверные ручки и поручни).',
        '\nНосите с собой одноразовые салфетки и всегда прикрывайте нос и рот, когда вы кашляете или чихаете, '
        '\nи утилизируйте их после использования.',
        '\nНосите обязательно с собой дезинфицирующее средство для рук, '
        '\nчтобы в любой обстановке вы могли очистить их.',
        '\nЧасто проветривайте помещение.',
        '\nРасскажите детям о профилактике коронавируса.']
return random.choice(text)
```

Сверху функция которая позволяет рандомно вытаскивать элементы списка.

Тут снизу я пытался написать цикл, но этот цикл не останавливается, испробовал очень много способов, но не смог реализовать. При нажатии в боте кнопки Остановить он должен прекратить работу

```
i = 1
if message.text == 'Напомни через 30 минут':
    while i:
        time.sleep(2)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, '{}'.format(random_rus_30m()), reply_markup=start_stop_button_rus())

if message.text == 'Остановить':
    return i + 5, bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Вы остановили бот', reply_markup=rus_lang())
```

Comment: Цикл где-то в другом месте должен быть, выше по коду. Где вы получаете message? Это должно быть где-то внутри цикла, а не снаружи.

Comment: Да, я попробовал во внутрь его положить результат не меняется

Comment: Покажите кусок кода побольше. Где вы получаете новый message?

Comment: Я могу скинуть вам ссылку на гитхаб?

Comment: Кидайте. Да достаточно просто показать в чём эта штука вообще крутится, внутри чего. И что вы вообще собственно хотите получить. Я вообще не понимаю, зачем вам цикл тут, что вы хотите сделать в итоге. Нарисуйте себе сначала блок-схему того, как у вас управление должно передаваться, а потом уже пишите код.

Comment: Цикл я решил использовать для того чтобы он каждые 30мин отправлял напоминания, кнопка Остановить должна была останавливать этот цикл, но у меня не получается это реализовать, так как это мой первый проект и нет опыта. Не могу понят где я допустил ошибку. Ссылка:https://github.com/ChyngyzOsmonov/wash_hand_bot

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю, как правильно такое в чатботе сделать. По идее надо отдельный процесс запускать, который через какое-то время должен послать команду, а другой командой можно было бы как-то прервать этот процесс. Но как это правильно сделать... Но явно не циклом.